# pyTTSX3 ничего не говорит

Tags: python, pyttsx3

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys

def talk(words):
    engine=pyttsx3.init("dummy")
    engine.say(words)
    engine.runAndWait()

talk("Hi")
```

Ничего не произносится, хотя программа успешно завершает выполнение

Comment: `pyttsx3.init("dummy")`, dummy ???

Comment: Без dummy выдает ошибку

Comment: какую??????????

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\79220\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\79220\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Answer (score 0):

Может быть?

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys

def talk(words):
    engine=pyttsx3.init("dummy")
    engine.say(words)
    engine.runAndWait()

talk("Hi")
```